# Hierarchical data pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to analyze data from a simulation. The data is organized by the structure of the model:

I.e. the Model has Nodes. Each node has a position and a speed. Each position has an x, y and z component. Each component has a value for every time step in the simulation.

To organize the data I began writing an object that stores all the values so that I can get to a time series of a component by calling something like:

```
values = simulation.nodes(13).position.x(:)
```

Then I heard about pandas and how it provides some usefull sorting and analysis tools. Could I use pandas to do what I want to do? Or should I write my own object using ndarrays?

Thanks for your answers.

Ben

Comment: Pandas is a data sorting module. You should use it if you want to automatically sort your data before putting it into a model. Although based on what I'm ready from your question I would say no you don't but I might be wrong about what you are try to convey.

Comment: @PrestonHager No, Pandas is not a data sorting module. It _allows_ you to sort data if you want, and it offers a number of operations that work better on sorted data, but sorting is not its primary purpose. It was developed to do time-series analysis but has acquired a lot of general statistical methods.

Comment: Ok, I'm not very good at pandas. And haven't explored it in great depth yet. Thanks @DavidZ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Pandas can do what you want. I'd recommend using a [`Panel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Panel.html), a three-dimensional data structure. If we consider the panel to be divided into rows, columns, and layers, then each layer could correspond to a node, each column could correspond to a measurement (so you'd have six columns, three for the components of position and three more for the components of velocity), and each row to a time. The `Panel` has methods that make it easy to sort the data by whatever criteria you like, to extract the parts corresponding to certain times or time ranges or certain nodes, to resample, interpolate, and otherwise process the data, and even to separate the position data from the velocity data. You would probably find it helpful to use a [`MultiIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html) for the columns, which allows you to have multi-level column labels that combine into groups - that way you could have a group for position and another group for velocity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would it be a good Idea to create a custom type ie "vector" and store three reals in it and then put many vectors in the panel?

Comment: No, probably not. Much of the convenience of using Panels disappears when you put arbitrary objects in them, rather than numbers. It depends on what you would want to do with those vectors, but you will probably be better off just doing the corresponding mathematical operations with the Panel. That could be material for a followup question, after you have tried it yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I have a better understanding now of what pandas is actually there for.